# Database structure for storing a list of GPS positions for multiple aircraft

Tags: java, database

I wish to implement a program to monitor the GPS positions of multiple aircraft. I will recieve updated positions every minute and wish to keep a log of each aircraft so that it would be possible to analyse the data and draw routes on a map.

I am wondering what would be the best way of approaching this. At the moment I can only think of have a table with 3 main fields: ID of aircraft, TimeStamp (increments by 1 after every update) and the position. [So say there are 100 aircraft, then every minute 100 new records would be added]. I would then query the aircraft ID to receive the log of positions. Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: You will want your timestamp to be an actual time, not a counter. Otherwise, if you miss a collection cycle, your aircraft will appear to be accelerating wildly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Oedum answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478416/database-structure-for-storing-a-list-of-gps-positions-for-multiple-aircraft/12478475#12478475), you would have two tables.

```
Aircraft
--------
Aircraft ID
Aircraft identification


Position
--------
Aircraft ID
Timestamp
X Position
Y Position
Altitude
```

The key to the Position table is a combined key.  The Aircraft ID, ascending, and the Timestamp, **descending**.

That way, you can easily retrieve the most recent position, as well as all of the positions.  They would be sorted in most recent to least recent order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split up your position into I guess two.
To something like:

```
ID
Timestamp
X-cordinate
Y-coordinate
```

Comment: Aircrafts fly in three dimensions so I guess also a Z-position ;)

Comment: Planes aren't in planes you say?!